# What would be a correct term to describe a "cheesy" line?

Tags: word-requests

I'm looking for either an adjective or a noun, that describes lines like

> 僕は死ぬまであなたのことを忘れない！
>
> 僕は永遠に君のことを愛してる！
>
> 僕はずっとここで待ってる！

Yeah, you know, these over-melodramatic lines in dramas with sad violin music playing in the background at the end of the script.

A dictionary tells me （ド）派手 , but the example sentences only show it being used to describe flashy clothes.

Comment: This sounds like something that might be expressed in Japanese as something that's uncool. The words ダサい and 格好悪い come to mind, but neither mean 1-to-1 what you're looking for.

Answer (score 8):

How about...

> - [臭]{くさ}い・くさい・クサい
> - クサい[台詞]{せりふ}
> - くっさー！ (← Is this Kansai dialect?)

or...

> - [安]{やす}っぽいセリフ
> - [陳腐]{ちんぷ}なセリフ

... maybe?

Comment: 「キザなセリフ」って、古いですかね・・

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to the options that have already been raised, the first option that came to my mind was something along the lines of ベタすぎるセリフ (literally "an excessively cliched line").

I think a lot of the options that have been raised so far sound a bit more overtly negative than "cheesy" (which is usually disparaging but in an affectionate way); ベタ seems perhaps a bit closer to "cheesy" in that respect for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add to the choices already out there.

歯の浮くようなセリフ is a phrase that comes to mind. Literally it means a "line that makes one set one's teeth on edge", or how I would put it, a "line that is cringe-worthy".

Or maybe something even simpler, like 恥ずかしいセリフ "a line that's embarrassing (note the embarrassing is referring to the line itself)" or 痛い "so embarrasing it's hard to bear (this is a bit slangy)".  寒い is another word you can use to describe, meaning dull or corny.

Answer (score 0):

You could say the above lines sound affected or unnatural and are deliberately going for dramatic effect, in which case わざとらしい is a good fit. I first encountered this phrase in Saga no Gabai baachan, where the author describes a tearjerker scene in a drama that is put there on purpose to make the viewers break down and sob.

Otherwise, if you think the lines are uncool or cheesy, psosuna's suggestion of ダサい and 格好悪い is a nice one, especially if you're describing the feeling and emotional reaction it elicits.

Chocolate's is also very good, I think.